# Error on start-up Debian Squeeze (No init found)

Tags: linux

This morning my notebook decided to give me a nice present:

```
Killed
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

The strange thing is that I switch on the first time Debian and I logged in successfully. Then I try to open Emacs and the program window did not appear but the CPU usage immediately go up to 100% of usage! I saw with top command that the process was in bg, but nothing appeared to me. So I killed brutally the emacs process and I try again to open it. Nothing. The same scenario. So I try to reboot the system and it appeared to me that error!

I also have Windows 7 installed and so I try to log in in. Windows says me that some errors on the disk created problems, so I follow the instrucion to recovery and now I can log in in Windows, but not in Linux. I already did the Windows scan disk for all the disk, but the problem continue. And I cannot enter on Linux.

Probably I can try with the Debian live cd-rom, but I haven't still do it.

Comment: A live CD that does an fsck would be the first thing to do. You probably got disk errors.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately now I'm not at home and I don't have live cd. But I'll try with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a hardware failure (disk perhaps), or some boot sector issue, or something else.

Try running `smartctl` from the [smartmontools](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net) package.

Comment: I don't know this tool, I'll try it. I hope to resolve. Thanks for now!

Comment: But I believe you have a disk failure, because disks are the weakest part of laptops. If you need to replace it, consider replacing by an SSD (if you can afford it).

Comment: The fact is firt I have to save many data that I need and that I have on linux. I'm trying to save it from Windows, but I cannot enter in my "home" folder. o_O

Comment: I think it is easier to do on Linux, but you need to know Linux quite well to do that.

Comment: Ok. I can enter in my Home and now I'm saving all that I need. Then I try smartmontools.

Comment: Yes yes, I know is better on Linux, but from the terminal I can't see all. So is for this reason that I try to do it on Winzoz!! :P

Comment: Finally I solved the problem.

I run a live distro of Linux and I fixed with:

fdisk -l

fsck.ext4 -cfpv /dev/sda7 (sda7 is the part where I installed the root).

It seems to be ok all of the system!

thanks for the advice of smartmontools!